# custom cck field validation for singel field in drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

My requirement is i have a field created using CCK in Drupal 6, for which i want to check if that is unique. Is there any possibility to alter the validation only for that particular field and continuing the remaining fields with normal validation set in CCK ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a [validation function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#validate) in [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) or (more efficient) in [hook_form_FROM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/6).

Comment: will this not override the basic validation that is set for other CCK fields created?

Comment: No. `$form['#validate']` is an array that can contain multiple validation functions. All of them will get called.